# Is the much hyped REST API just a http method plus HATEOAS links?

Tags: rest, http

I read that HATEOAS links are the one that separates a REST API from a normal http API. In that case, does REST need a separate name? I wonder what all this hype about REST API is about. It seems to be just a http method with one extra rule in the response.
Q) What other differences exist?

Comment: You are right that most is incorrect hype by people who didn't care to read the actual document describing what REST means.

Comment: I just get the feeling that most people simply create http methods and say 'we create REST APIs.' May be, because it is a fashionable thing to do. 
 The more and more I try to find the difference between REST and the http, the more and more I feel that they are the same.
Can you throw some light on what REST actually means and how it differs from normal http?

Comment: ReST is described in <https://roy.gbiv.com/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm>. It's an architectural style, not a protocol. Most people nowadays associate "ReST" with "using HTTP properly". That's misleading.

Answer (score 4):

> I read that HATEOAS links are the one that separates a REST API from a normal http API.

That's probably a little bit of an understatement.  When [Leonard Richardson (2008)](https://qconsf.com/sf2008/dl/qcon-sanfran-2008/slides_/LeonardRichardson.pdf) described the "technology stack" of the web, he listed:

- URI
- HTTP
- HTML

A way of exploring the latter is to consider how HTML, as a media type, differs from a text document with URI in it.  To my mind, the key element is links and forms -- standardized ways of encoding into the representation the *semantics* of a URI (this is a link to another page, this is an embedded image, this is an embedded script, this is a form...).

Mike Admundsen, 2010:

> Hypermedia Types are MIME media types that contain native hyper-linking semantics that induce application flow. For example, HTML is a hypermedia type; XML is not.

[Atom Syndication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287)/[Atom Publishing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) is a good demonstration for defining a REST API.

> Can you throw some light on what REST actually means and how it differs from normal http?

Have you noticed that websites don't normally use plain text for the representations of the information that they share?  It's something of a dead end -- raw text doesn't have any hypermedia semantics built into it, so a generic client can't do anything more interesting than search for sequences that might be URI.

On the other hand, with HTML we have link semantics: we can include references to images, to style sheets, to scripts, as well as linking to other documents.  We can describe forms, that allow the creation of parameterized HTTP requests.

Additionally, that means that if some relation shouldn't be used by the client, the server can easily change the representation to remove the link.

Furthermore, the use of the hypermedia representation allows the server to use a richer description of which request message should be sent by the client.

Consider, for example, Google.  They can use the form to control whether search requests use GET or POST.  They can remove the "I Feel Lucky" option, or arrange that it redirects to the main experience.  They can embed additional information in to the fields of the form, to track what is going on.  They can choose which URI targets are used in the search results, directing the client to send to Google another request which gets redirected to the actual target, with additional meta data embedded in the query parameters, *all without requiring any special coordination with the client used*.

For further discussion, see Leonard Richardson's [slide deck from QCon 2008](https://www.crummy.com/writing/speaking/2008-QCon/), or Phil Sturgeon's [REST and Hypermedia in 2019](https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/rest-and-hypermedia-in-2019).

> Does n't think the client need to read the documentation if the HATEOAS link is a POST API? HATEOAS links will only guide you to an API but will not throw any light on how its request body needs to be filled....GET won't have request body. So, not much or a problem. but POST API?

Sort of - here's [Fielding writing in 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742):

> REST doesn’t eliminate the need for a clue. What REST does is concentrate that need for prior knowledge into readily standardizable forms.

On the web, the common use case is agents assisting human beings; the humans can resolve certain ambiguities on their own.  The result is a separation of responsibilities; the humans decode the domain specific semantics of the messages, the clients determine the right way to describe an interaction as an HTTP request.

If we want to easily replace the human with a machine, then we'll need to invest extra design capital in a message schema that expresses the domain specific semantics as clearly as we express the plumbing.

Comment: Good.. Liked the last paragraph in particular. That hypermedia can be of great help to the client. Gives him ways to explore. Without the need of any knowledge beforehand, the client knows what he can do next.

Comment: "all without requiring any special coordination with the client used." Does n't think the client need to read the documentation if the HATEOAS link is a POST API?  HATEOAS links will only guide you to an API but will not throw any light on how its request body needs to be filled....GET won't have request body. So, not much or a problem. but POST API?

Answer (score 2):

To me, REST is an ideology you want to aim for if you have a system that should last for years to come which has the freedom to evolve freely without breaking stuff on parts you can't control. This is very similar to the Web where a server can't control browsers directly though browsers are able to cooperate with any changes done to Web site representations returned by the server.

> I read that HATEOAS links are the one that separates a REST API from a normal http API. In that case, does REST need a separate name?

REST does basically what its name implies, it transfers the state of a resource representation. If so, we should come up with a new name for such "REST" APIs that are truly RPC in the back, to avoid confusion.

If you read through the [Richardson Maturity Model (RMM)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) you might fall under the impression that links or hypermedia controls as Fowler named it, which are mandatory at Level 3, are the feature that separates REST from normal HTTP interaction. However, Level 3 is just not enough to reach the ultimate goal of decoupling.

Most so called "REST APIs" do put a lot of design effort into pretty URIs in a way to express meaning of the target resource to client developer. They come up with fancy documentation generated by their tooling support, such as [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) or similar stuff, which the client developer has to follow stringent or they wont be able to interact with their API. Such APIs are RPC though. You won't be able to point the same client that interacts with API A to point to API B now and still work out of the box as they might use completely different endpoints and return different types of data for almost the same named resource endpoint. A client that is attempting to use a bit more of dynamic behavior might learn the type from parsing the endpoint and expect a URI such as `.../api/users` to return users, when all of a sudden now the API changed its URI structure to something like `.../api/entities`. What would happen now? Most of these clients would break, a clear hint that the whole interaction model doesn't follow the one outline by a REST architecture.

REST puts emphasis on link relation names that should give clients a stable way of learning the URIs intent by allowing a URI to actually change over time. A URI basically is attached to a link relation name and basically represents an affordance, something that is clear what it does. I.e. the affordance of a button could be that you can press it and something would happen as a result. Or the affordance of a light switch would be that a light goes on or off depending on the toggled state of the light switch.

Link relation names now express such an affordance and are a text-based way to represent something like a trash bin or pencil symbol next to table entry on a Web page were you might figure out that on clicking one will delete an entry from the table while the other symbol allows to edit that entry. Such link relation names should be either [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), use [widely accepted ontologies](http://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/) or use [custom link-relation extensions as outlined by RFC 8288 (Web Linking)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2)

It is important to note however, that a URI is just a URI which should not convey a semantic meaning to a client. This does not mean that a URI can't have a semantic meaning to the server or API, but a client should not attempt to deduce one from the URI itself. This is what the link-relation name is for, which provides the infrequently changing part of that relation. An endpoint might be referenced by multiple, different URIs, some of which might use different query parameters used for filtering. According to Fielding each of these URIs represent different resources:

> The definition of resource in REST is based on a simple premise: **identifiers should change as infrequently as possible**. Because the Web uses embedded identifiers rather than link servers, authors need an identifier that closely matches the semantics they intend by a hypermedia reference, allowing the reference to remain static even though the result of accessing that reference may change over time. REST accomplishes this by **defining a resource to be the semantics of what the author intends to identify, rather than the value corresponding to those semantics at the time the reference is created**. It is then left to the author to ensure that the identifier chosen for a reference does indeed identify the intended semantics. (Source [6.2.1](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm))

As URIs are used for caching results, they basically represent the keys used for caching the response payload. As such, it gets obvious that on adding additional query parameters to URIs used in `GET` requests, you end up bypassing caches as the key is not stored in the cache yet and therefore get the result of a different resource, even though it might be identical (also in response representation) as the URI without that additional parameter.

> I wonder what all this hype about REST API is about. It seems to be just a http method with one extra rule in the response.

In short, this is what those self- or marketing-termed pseudo "REST APIs" do convey and many people seem to understand.

The hype for "REST" arose from the inconveniences put onto developers on interacting with other interop-solutions such as Corba, RMI or SOAP where often partly-commercial third-party libraries and frameworks had to be used in order to interact with such systems. Most languages supported HTTP both as client and server out of the box removing the requirement for external libraries or frameworks per se. In addition to that, RPC based solution usually require certain stub- or skeleton-classes to be generated first, which was usually done by the build pipeline automatically. Upon updates of the IDL, such as WSDL linking or including XSD schemata, the whole stub-generation needed to be redone and the whole code needed to looked through in order to spot whether a breaking change was added or not. Usually no obvious changelog was available which made changing or updating such stuff a pain in the ...

In those pseudo "REST" APIs plain JSON is now pretty much the de facto standard, avoiding the step of generating stub classes and the hazzle of analyzing the own code to see whether some of the forced changes had a negative impact on the system. Most of those APIs use some sort of URI based versioning allowing a developer to see based on the URI whether something breaking was introduced or not, mimicking some kind of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

The problem with those solution though is, that not the response representation format itself is versioned but the whole API itself leading to common issues when only a change on a part of the API should be introduced as now the whole API's version needs to be bumped. In addition to that, to URIs such as `.../api/v1/users/1234` and `.../api/v2/users/1234` may represent the same user and thus the same resource though are in fact different by nature as the URI is different.

> Q) What other differences exist?

While REST is just an architecture model that can't force you to implement it stringent, you simply will not benefit from its properties if you ignore some of its [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints). As mentioned above, HATEOAS support is therefore not yet enough to really decouple all clients from an API and thus allow to benefit from the REST architecture.

RMM unfortunately does not talk about media types at all. A media type basically specifies how a received payload should be processed and defines the semantics and constraints of each of the elements used within that payload. I.e. if you look at [`text/html`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html) registered in [IANA's media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), you can see that it points to the [published specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html), which always references the most recent version of HTML. HTML is designed in a way to stay backwards compatible so no special versioning stuff is required.

HTML provides, IMO, two important things:

- [semi-structured content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_data)
- form support

The former one allows to structure data, giving certain segments or elements the possibility to express different semantics defined in the media type. I.e. a browser will handle an image differently than a div element or an article element. A crawler might favor links and content contained in an article element and ignore script and image elements completely. Based on the existence or absence of certain elements even certain processing differences may occur.

Including support for forms is a very important thing in REST actually as this is the feature which allows a server to teach a client on what a server needs as input. Most so called "REST APIs" just force a developer to go through their documentation, which might be outdated, incorrect or incomplete, and send data to a predefined endpoint according to the documentation. In case of outdated or incomplete documentation, how should a client ever be able to send data to the server? Moreover, a server might never be able to change as basically the documentation is now the truth and the API has to align with the documentation.

Unfortunately, form-support is still a bit in its infancy. Besides HTML, which provides `<form>...</form>`, you have a couple of JSON based form attempts such as [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo-json (halform)](http://halform.herokuapp.com/), [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) or [hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/). None of these have yet wide library or framework support yet as some of these form representations still have not finalized their specification on how to support forms more effectively.

Other media-types, unfortunately, might not use semi-structured content or provide support for forms that teach a client on the needs of a server, though they are still valuable to REST in general. First, through [Web linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288) link support can be added to media types that do not naturally support those. Second, the data itself does not really need to be text-based at all in order for an application to use it further. I.e. pictures an videos usually are encoded and byte based anyways still a client can present them to users.

The main point about media-types though is, as Fielding already [pointed out](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) in one of his cited blog posts, is, that representations shouldn't be confused with types. Fielding stated that:

> A REST API should never have “typed” resources that are significant to the client. Specification authors may use resource types for describing server implementation behind the interface, but those types must be irrelevant and invisible to the client. The only types that are significant to a client are the current representation’s media type and standardized relation names.

Jørn Wildt explained in an excellent blog post what a [`"typed" resource`](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) is and why a REST architecture shouldn't use such types. Basically, to sum the blog post up, a client expecting a `../api/users` endpoint to return a pre-assumed data payload might break if the server adds additional, unexpected fields, renames existing fields or leave out expected fields. This coupling can be avoided by using simple [content-type negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) where a client informs a server on which capabilities the client supports and the client will chose the representation that best fits the target resource. If the server can't support the client with a representation the client supports the server should respond with a failure (or a default representation) the client might log to inform the user.

This in essence is exactly what the name REST stands for, the transfer of a resource's state representation where the representation may differ depending on the representation format defined by the selected media type. While HATEOAS may be one of the most obvious changes between REST and a non-REST based HTTP solution, this for sure is not the only factor that makes up a payload in REST. I hope I could shed some light on the decoupling intention and that a server should teach clients what the server expects through forms and that the affordance of URIs is captured by link-relation names. All these tiny aspects in sum make up REST, and you will only benefit from REST, unfortunately, if you respect all of its constraints and not only those that are either easy to obtain or what you have the mood for implementing.

Comment: Good one ...
Richardson Maturity Model (RMM) - Yes...according to this,I felt that it is only HATEOAS links that set a REST API apart from a normal http. At least, that is the only concrete difference I could find so far.
Q1) I understand the importance of links in REST. But, was it not possible to populate this in the response of SOAP itself, which was the predecessor of REST? Just adding one more element in the response of SOAP.....
Q2) If that had been done, I doubt whether REST API could have taken birth because without links, REST loses its raison d'etre.

Comment: Q3) HATEOAS - These links cannot eliminate the need for documentation in case of a POST API. They give information on the URL of an API but do not throw any light on the fields in the request. How can a client know about the request then without reading the documentation of that link API?
Therefore, I think all that the links can do is just guide the client to an API and the client then needs to go through the documentation to find out how to fill the fields in the request. So, we cannot do away with documentation. Do you agree?

Comment: SOAP is something inherently different. SOAP basically sends a message to a remote host to execute a specific method or operation. It therefore uses one single endpoint only. Linking within requests and responses does not make any sense here. What should a link express? The WSDL containing the XSD scheme already defines how the request and response look like. REST is more like interacting with documents where documents may contain pointers to other documents. The linking is done via URIs, though URIs itself don't represent operations itself, the interface of the transport protocol is used here

Comment: Ad Q3, so you need a documentation to fill out a form in a browser where you can click a button to submit the data to the server? In certain scenarios, especially when the document to transfer might be very difficult, think of certain e-government or EDI documents, certain hints for non-experts might for sure be benefitial. Think of mouse-over texts on hovering over labels or text fields. Link-relations may also point to further documentation, tough this is not mandatory. In case of an automated client, do you think the client will read through and understand external documentation?

Comment: Automated client..may not be able to read.. but consider this example ..There is a book doctor appointment API that gives reschedule appointment API as hateoas link -
"link" :"appointment/reschedule/appointmentID"
"rel":XXX
This reschedule API may take some fields such as new time, doctor id etc.... But, if you were the client, how would you know that info through the above link relations without reading doc? You will only know that you can call the reschedule API but not how.

Comment: All the information you need is provided by the server. At one point you have a link to reschedule an appointment, which upon invoking the link will provide you with a form representation your client supports. This form may contain pre-filled data on the current schedule which you may change and send to the service again. This is a common update-like scenario on the Web. I'm not sure why or where you need some documentation here exactly. Probably you still think in the mindset of a typical RPC service?!

Comment: Yes, of course clients need to provide some kind of dynamic interface that does render the response and present it to the user instead of shipping pre-made UI components that map field X to widget-element Y.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by REST uses the same interaction model as the Web. REST is just a technique that allows applications to "surf" the Web as we humans do. REST, after all, is just a generalization of the browseable Web. It is probably beneficial to design a client on top of a [state machine](https://nordicapis.com/designing-a-true-rest-state-machine/) as well, this might also give you an example how the interaction flow using HATEOAS may look like in the outlined toaster example

Comment: "REST, after all, is just a generalization of the browseable Web." - But the buzz and the hype around the word REST led me(or may lead anyone) to think that the idea of REST is something out of the box.  But, the underlying principle was already used in Web. We are only trying to adopt it from Web to this one.

Comment: No, it is nothing new in general, to application-driven distributed systems it is somekind of new though as RPC based solutions were prevailing until then